Unable to use event slot in vuetify <v-calendar>
I am using Vuetify v-calendar. Here is my code:
<v-calendar
        ref="calendar"
        v-model="value"
        :disabled="isLoading|| (adminUser && noUserOrClientSelected)"
        :events="events"
        :view-mode="type"
        :weekdays="weekday"
        :intervals="12"
        :interval-start="6"
        @update:model-value="UpdateModelValue"
      >
        <template #event="{ event }">
          <div> {{ event.customer_name }} - {{ event.title }}</div>
        </template>
      </v-calendar>

However,I continue to see the default title on the calendar event, and not "customer_name - title". I don't get any errors or warnings. Looks like the event slot is not being recognised. I am using vue 3.5.13 and vuetify 3.7.5.
Any suggestion, how to fix the issue?
Update: The event slot works when the calendar is in Month mode. However, it does not work in the Week mode. It is possible that this is a bug.
Have look at the Veutify play link, which uses an even slot in month mode, and it work. If switch the calendar in the week mode, the slot does not work.

Tried it with the example from the documentation and it seems to work as expected. Can you provide an example showing the issue?

I believe that you tried the calendar in the month mode. In the month mode, the event slot works. Please try the link I have provided above where the event slot works. Next change the mode to week and check if the event slot works.

Oh, yes, sorry. Looks like you are right, in month mode, the event slot is passed on to nested components (see code), but not in week or day mode (Lines 168 & 178). Looks like you already created a bug report on github. Doesn't seem like there is a workaround, except using the (string-only) title property.

Yes, I have created a bug report. Let us hope that someone fixes the bug soon. I need to use the calendar in the week mode, but I can’t.
